# What can I do if someone downvote all my questions and my answers?

Tags: support, down-votes, tag-abuse

Bad surprise this afternoon, all my questions and a part of my answers have been downvoted...

Someone takes 10 minutes to downvote all my question on by one and I don't understand why

I don't care about the reputation points I have lost, but it is just not fair. I spent time to help people with success in most of case, my answers don't deserve this behavior.

What can I do?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1109988/sdespont?tab=reputation

Comment: Should be reversed by the serial voting script some time around midnight (UTC). If it isn't reversed after 24 hours or so, you may poke a moderator to look into it.

Comment: Sit back, relax, and wait for the automatic serial-voting-reversal script to kick in. Wait 24 hours at least to see it's effects. 36 downvotes like that are *just* what that script was designed for.

Comment: Wow, that looks impressive, actually. There may be the odd legitimate downvote among them, but that's a good meal for the script ;)

Comment: If you want a preview of what will occur, take a look at my rep tab; I recently had the same thing happen. The system caught it: http://stackoverflow.com/users/656243/lynn-crumbling?tab=reputation

Comment: @DanielFischer, and all others : Thanks for your comments. Any possibilities to know which user have done this? Voting is anonymous, but I would like understand the user's motivation.

Comment: No way. If you have a suspicion, you could be able to check and gain some confidence. Wouldn't hold up in court, though.

Comment: @sdespont: no, that won't happen. Ignore it, it's not worth your time worrying about it.

Comment: Mine was a result of a downvote with a comment that the user's answer wasn't pertinent to the question. I'd guess most cases follow a similar pattern: your downvote accompanied by a comment. Don't let this prevent you from leaving comments with your downvotes, though... most users will not react like this.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok, I will just let it go. But for my information, is the user will receive an (automatic ?) warning e-mail from the moderators?

Comment: I'm not sure, you could visit the [Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) and ping a moderator to ask.

Comment: Feel bad for you.

Comment: You said something about someone and royally pissed him off as a result. That's pretty much it. I'll give him a good talking-to, so you can consider this handled. As mentioned, the script will undo the votes in due time.